# Why does the list not save the elements?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
while(True):
    size,times = map(int,input().split())
    v=list(map(int,input().split()))
    store=dict()
    for i in range(size):
        store[v[i]]=list()
        store[v[i]].append(i+1)
        print(store)
    while(times>0):
        pos,num = map(int,input().split())
```

For example:

`size=8` (input array size) `times=4`

`pos=1` (The position of num in list start by 1) `num=3`

```
{1: [1]}
{1: [1], 3: [2]}
{1: [1], 3: [2], 2: [3]}
{1: [1], 3: [2], 2: [4]}
{1: [1], 3: [2], 2: [4], 4: [5]}
{1: [1], 3: [6], 2: [4], 4: [5]}
{1: [1], 3: [6], 2: [7], 4: [5]}
{1: [8], 3: [6], 2: [7], 4: [5]}
```

Things I want:

```
{1: [1]}
{1: [1], 3: [2]}
{1: [1], 3: [2], 2: [3]}
{1: [1], 3: [2], 2: [3,4]}
{1: [1], 3: [2], 2: [3,4], 4: [5]}
{1: [1], 3: [2,6], 2: [4], 4: [5]}
{1: [1], 3: [2,6], 2: [3,4,7], 4: [5]}
{1: [1,8], 3: [2,6], 2: [3,4,7], 4: [5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line `store[v[i]]=list()` is creating a new list every time

remove it and change the next append line to:

```
store.setdefault(v[i], list()).append(i+1)
```

That will create the list only if it doesn't exist.

Alternatively use `collections.defaultdict(list)`